# Randomly distributing values across multiple rows in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames.
`DF1` contains unique ID's which are assigned to an area and a count of how many people are in each ID. (the `COUNT` column).
`DF2` contains how many more or less people need to be assigned an area (the `CHANGE` column).

Is there an efficient way of, in the case of Area A for example, adding the extra 24 people from `CHANGE` column in `DF2` to the `COUNT` column in `DF1` randomly across the rows assigned to Area A.
Thank you.

```
DF1 <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow=20, ncol=3))
DF1[,1] <- 1:20
DF1[,2] <- rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each=5)
DF1[,3] <- sample(10:30,20,rep=TRUE)
colnames(DF1) <- c("ID","AREA","COUNT")

DF2 <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow=4, ncol=2))
DF2[,1] <- c("A","B","C","D")
DF2[,2] <- c(24,-17,-1,5)
colnames(DF2) <- c("AREA","CHANGE")
```

EDIT:
This is my current solution. However, my actual dataset contains thousands of rows and takes a few hours to complete. Hence why I am after a more efficient way of achieving the same goal.

```
for (i in 1:length(unique(DF2[,1]))){
DF_Area <- unique(DF1[,2])
DF1_Subset <- with(DF1, DF1[AREA == DF_Area[i],])
DF2_Row <- DF2[DF2$AREA %in% DF_Area[i],]

if(DF2_Row$CHANGE!=0){
DF1_Update <- as.data.frame(DF1_Subset$COUNT)

if(DF2_Row$CHANGE>=0){ALLOCATION_VALUE <- 1}else{ALLOCATION_VALUE <- -1}

for (GG in 1:abs(DF2_Row$CHANGE)){
DF1_Update_Row <- sample(which(DF1_Update > 0),1)
DF1_Update[DF1_Update_Row, ] <- DF1_Update[DF1_Update_Row, ] + ALLOCATION_VALUE}

DF1_Subset$COUNT <- DF1_Update[,1]
DF1$COUNT[match(DF1$ID, DF1_Subset$ID, nomatch = 0) != 0] <- DF1_Subset$COUNT[match(DF1$ID, DF1_Subset$ID, nomatch = 0)]}}
```

Comment: @timat I have added my current solution to the question. I feels like there should be a more efficient way of doing it though.

Comment: do all areas always have 5 rows/entries? In that case, can we change to `DF1[,1] <- rep(1:5,4)` ?

Comment: @Aramis7d They do not. I simplified it for my example. The areas have differing numbers of rows/entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does work for any number of area and with any ID number but it can give a negative count if too much people are removed in an ID

```
library(data.table)

DF1 <- as.data.table(DF1,key="ID")
DF1$AREA <- as.factor(DF1$AREA)  #to change area as level
dt_all <-NULL

for (i in levels(DF1$AREA)) {

  if (DF2[DF2$AREA == i,]$CHANGE != 0) {
    bool_pos <- (DF2[DF2$AREA == i,]$CHANGE > 0) #to know to add or remove from count

    ID <- sample(1:(length(DF1[AREA == i,]$ID)),abs(DF2[DF2$AREA == i,]$CHANGE), rep=TRUE)
    ID <- DF1[AREA == i,]$ID[ID] # select random id for each value in change
    df_temp <- as.data.table(table(ID),key="ID") 
    df_temp$ID <- as.integer(df_temp$ID)
    if (!bool_pos) {
      df_temp$N <- (df_temp$N)*-1
    }

    dt_all <- rbind(dt_all,df_temp )
  }
}

DF1 <- merge(DF1, dt_all,all.x=TRUE, by="ID")  
DF1[is.na(N), N:=0]
DF1[, COUNT:=COUNT+N]
DF1[,N:=NULL]
dt_all <-NULL
```

Comment: @Chris I improve the solution, now the loop is only on the number of ID instead of the total number of change.. It still can be improve using data.table

Comment: @Chris even faster with data.table. Now there's only one loop on the area value.

Comment: This works great except when there are 0 values in the CHANGE column in my real data. I shall have a go editing your code to bypass this problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Now it should work with the 0. I just add a if condition at the beginning of the loop

Comment: I have used your revised answer with my actual data and it runs without any problems (and a lot quicker). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should also work (where the random numbers are generated each time by dividing the total CHANGE into equal intervals from which each of the remaining numbers are to be generated). Also, use `split` instead of subsetting inside loop, it will be faster.

```
set.seed(100)
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(DF1, DF1$AREA),
       function(x) {
         tot <- DF2[DF2$AREA == unique(x[,'AREA']),]$CHANGE # total change needed
         n <- nrow(x)
         nums <- rep(0, n)
         part.tot <- 0
         for (i in 1:(n-1)) {
           lb <- min(0, tot-part.tot)
           ub <- max(0, tot-part.tot)
           nums[i] <- round(runif(1, lb, ub)/(n-i+1)) # divide the remaining CHANGE into (n-i+1) equal parts
           part.tot <- part.tot + nums[i]
         }
         nums[n] <- tot - part.tot # assign the remaining to the last element
         x['COUNT'] <- x['COUNT'] + nums
         x
       }))

      ID AREA COUNT
#A.1   1    A    14
#A.2   2    A    30
#A.3   3    A    32
#A.4   4    A    27
#A.5   5    A    34
#B.6   6    B    27
#B.7   7    B    23
#B.8   8    B    18
#B.9   9    B    19
#B.10 10    B     5
#C.11 11    C    15
#C.12 12    C    19
#C.13 13    C    11
#C.14 14    C    19
#C.15 15    C    10
#D.16 16    D    30
#D.17 17    D    26
#D.18 18    D    19
#D.19 19    D    15
#D.20 20    D    20
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried it with my real data and it's not that much faster. Thanks for the advice about using split though, that will come in handy in the future.